# Dropdown Box cuts off a value?

Tags: javascript, php, html, drop-down-menu, mysqli

When I'm trying to call this script it first shows me to chose one.
Then I can chose from `8417 - 8422`, just like in the where clause.
But If I pick `8417`, it shows me the data for that id but shows me `8418` as selected.
After that `8417` isn't anymore in the dropbox! Then it only goes from `8418` to `8422`.

I can't find the mistake. Does anyone have any tipps?

```
$strSql= "SELECT id FROM tbl_person where id between 8417 and 8422";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$strSql) or die('Error generating Dropdown: '. mysqli_connect_error());

echo '<form><select size="1" name="ddKfz" class="dropID" onchange="ddChange(this.form)">';
$rs = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if (empty($rs)) {
    echo  "<option selected value='0' style='color:#cc0000'>Empty!</option>";
} else {
    if ($_REQUEST["ddKfz"]=="" or $_REQUEST["ddKfz"]==0 ) {
        echo  "<option selected value='0' style='color:#cc0000'>Please pick one:</option>";
        mysqli_data_seek($result, 0);
    }
    while ($rs = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $strOption= "Kfz: " . $rs["id"];
        if ($_REQUEST["ddKfz"]==$rs["id"])
            echo  "<option value='" . $rs["id"] . "'selected style='color:red'>" . $strOption . "</option>";
        else
            echo  "<option value='" . $rs["id"] . "' >" . $strOption . "</option>";  
    }
}
echo "</select></form>";
mysqli_free_result($result);
```

The function called by the Dropdown on Change

```
function ddChange(f) {
    f.method="post";
    f.action="index.php";
    f.submit();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do `$rs = mysqli_fetch_array($result);` on top. This already reads out the first row (8417). Instead use `$result->num_rows`:

```
echo '<form><select size="1" name="ddKfz" class="dropID" onchange="ddChange(this.form)">';
if($result->num_rows < 1) {
    echo  "<option selected value='0' style='color:#cc0000'>Empty!</option>";
    …
```

A few extra points to consider:

- Don't use `$_REQUEST`, use `$_POST` instead, and sanitize the data!
- You don't need `mysqli_data_seek($result, 0);`
  -`value='" . $rs["id"] . "'selected` is missing a space before `selected` (this might be why 8417 doesn't show up in the browser anymore)

Comment: I removed the data seek and edited a space before the selected. But now it shows only 8418 - 8422 from the beginning. The 8417 seems completely gone.. Thanks so far!

Comment: I think what I wrote above might be the problem.

Comment: Oh my god, thank you! The missing 8417 now stays permanent. :-) So is it in general better to use the Object oriented style instead of the procedural?

Comment: Its not better, but it can help with code consistency